# NSLayoutConstraint break within UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

When adding a `viewController.view` to a table view cell programmatically with autolayout constraints it sometimes not laid out correctly. Knowing that cells have fixed height (50) and the sub view contains a `UIButton` and a `UITableView` which doesn't contain cells at the begining  until the user do some action.
Here is the code that adds the sub view to the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    //Get sub item objects
    BookItem * newItem = self.subItems[indexPath.row];
    NSString * newItemKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", newItem.iD];
    NSString * currentCellItemKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", cell.tag];
    BookTreeItemViewController_iPad * bookTreeItemVC = self.subItemVCs[currentCellItemKey];
    if (!bookTreeItemVC)
    {
        bookTreeItemVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BookTreeItemViewController_iPad"];
        //Clear cell
        for (UIView * subView in cell.contentView.subviews)
            [subView removeFromSuperview];
        //Add sub item view to cell
        [bookTreeItemVC.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:bookTreeItemVC.view];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[item]|" options:nil metrics:nil views:@{@"item": bookTreeItemVC.view}]];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[item]|" options:nil metrics:nil views:@{@"item": bookTreeItemVC.view}]];
    }
    bookTreeItemVC.bookItem = newItem;

    //Replace the old book tree item view controller with the new one
    [self.subItemVCs setValue:nil forKey:currentCellItemKey];
    cell.tag = newItem.iD;
    self.subItemVCs[newItemKey] = bookTreeItemVC;

    return cell;
}
```

Here is the constraints warning:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c091240 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7c0895d0(49.5)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a74f250 V:[UIButton:0x7a7482a0'Title']-(8)-[UITableView:0x7aad7a00]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a74f2b0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7a74ee70]-(0)-[UIButton:0x7a7482a0'Title']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a74f310 V:[UITableView:0x7aad7a00]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7a74ef60]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7a739510 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7a74ee70(87)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7a74e2e0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7a74ee70]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7a74ee00 )>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7a747900 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7a74ef60(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7a748130 _UILayoutGuide:0x7a74ef60.bottom == UIView:0x7a74ee00.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a750c10 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7a74ee00]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7c0895d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a748270 V:[UIView:0x7a74ee00]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7c0895d0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a74f250 V:[UIButton:0x7a7482a0'Title']-(8)-[UITableView:0x7aad7a00]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

By the way, I've noticed from the warning that the top layout guide has a height of (87) which supposed to be (0)

Comment: Can you post your code. So that it is easy to identify

Comment: I've updated the post and added the code that adds the sub view and its constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of research I had to remove the table view of the sub view (The view that's put into the cell) from the IB (storyboard) and add it programmatically with its constraints. So, Every thing is ok now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right.

```
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7a739510 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7a74ee70(87)]>",
```

Somehow, your view controller has layout guide with top supporting value of 87. This crash with your fixed cell height, hence it is removing the constraint of distance between button and tableview.

Maybe you can post your layout code of the BookTreeItemViewController_iPad or

- try 3D debugging from new xcode to find out what is that 87 pixel ?
- set your TableView.rowHeight to UITableViewAutomaticDimension, so that your cell height will be dynamic. Then, again, you can see what is that 87 pixels.

Comment: From 3D view debugging, The sub views of the custom view are placed outside and above the container view.

Comment: that is correct, since it is subview. But is the custom view height show that additional 87 pixel, or it only show UIButton and UITableView? And how about the height combined of both the button and tableview? Is it under 50 pixel (your cell height)?

Comment: After making the cell height dynamic (Which I don't want) this warning appears "Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.
"

Comment: I mean the sub views are outside the container view bounds not only on front of it.

Comment: Hmm.. never see that warning before. But doesn't that mean your cell is somehow ended up with height 0? Is the ViewController (for the cell) initialized? Can you see the button on the cell? All I can think of is the ViewController that you want to add to the cell is somehow not initialized yet or the button's height is 0 since there is no minimum height specified for button height constraint.

Comment: What I mean by not initialize here is, viewdidload is not called before the view is added to the cell. So all the content layout of view controller is not created yet

Comment: The ViewController is initialized (see the code above). Even if the button and table view height is 0, there is a vertical space between the button and tableview equals 8.

Comment: Cancel this comment. Wrong press

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like when you are removing the view, your constraint is not getting removed. So just replace the below code:-

Replace :-

```
for (UIView * subView in cell.contentView.subviews)
 [subView removeFromSuperview];
```

TO:-

```
[cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

And also modiified the below in a more efficient way :-

```
NSView *views=bookTreeItemVC.view;
[cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[item]|" options:0l metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(views)]];
[cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[item]|" options:0l metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(views)]];
```

Comment: No, removing the view removes its constraints from its super view. I tested that.